# Whats the difference in these two php conditions?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

i am trying to check whther $_GET['id'] is set and is numeric else killing the code execution.,

following both codes are working for me , but would like to know whats the difference in between them ?

php condition 1

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || (isset($_GET['id']) && !is_numeric($_GET['id']))) {
die();
}
```

php condition 2

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
die();
}
```

Comment: No difference at all

Comment: ... except the second on e will be quicker

Comment: ... and the first one makes me mad. maaaaaaaaaaad.

Comment: @EdHeal thanks , thats what i wanted to know, in case of performacne.,

Comment: *that's what you wanted to know?*. oh my.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath dont make me delete my comment , out of shame :P , anyways i was confused which way to go., both looks identical.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the first one has an unnecessary extra check if `$_GET['id']` is set. PHP uses what is called short-circuit boolean evaluation, which means that if the left side of an `||` is true, the right side doesn't need to be evaluated. So, even in the second example, `!is_numeric($_GET['id'])` will never get evaluated unless `isset($_GET['id'])` is true.

Logically these statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You're basically doing

```
A || (!A && B)
```

if `A` is `true`, then the rest won't be executed.

If `A` is false, `!A` will be true anyway. So the `!A` is redundant.

Functionally they are the same, but in practice, you don't need the extra condition.

You can see the logical explanation here:

[image: Logic]

Answer (score -4):

In the first one 
It makes three checks which are unnecessary. 
In the second it won't catch one of the conditions required

|| means OR - either one of the conditions should evaluate to true

&& means AND - both conditions must be true

To work properly you need this

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) && !is_numeric[$_GET['id']])
    die();
```

The first statement does the same thing but it check if $_GET['id'] is set two times which isn't needed.

Comment: there should be || i guess.

Comment: I should probably stop using autocompletion :) Thanks

Comment: This code doesn't work, and will give a NOTICE about $_GET['id'] being undefined

Comment: @AMB If there is || and not && "foo" will pass as an id

Comment: @ehwas i tried above code and it passes "foo" as an id . thanks, my code if (!isset($_GET['id']) && !is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
die();
}else{
echo $_GET['id'];
}